# Contacts disappeared after adding new google account

Tags: contacts, samsung-nexus-s, google-account

I am using a Google Nexus S I9023 mobile phone (Android 4.0.4). For whatever reason my google account was deactivated. So, I registered a new one and added it to the phone.
Afterwards, 80% of the contacts in my contact list, disappeared. 
What happened and how can I restore them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lost all your contacts as it was tied to the old one, registered a new one, then when ICS sync'd, nothing there... as it was on a newly registered account.

Question is what happened to attribute you to getting your previous Google account closed?

Comment: I have no idea! I did not do anything out of the ordinary. But all this data has to be stored somewhere else right? I can't be only linked with that account!

Comment: Wait!!! When you say *deactivated* did you really mean, unlinked on the handset? Can you sign on the gmail with your old account? If not, as you say, then something is definitely wrong there, you need to raise the issue with Google to find out why your account got de-activated - breach of rules, spamming, what? no idea.

Comment: The thing is like this: they deactivated my account a while ago, but I payed no attention to it, because everything was fine. Today, I said to myself that I should look into the issue and thought that it would be easier to make a new account than report the case to google. I had no idea that the data was not stored locally! So, I made a new account, deleted the old account from the settings and afterwards... 80% of the contacts were just gone! It can't be possible that all the contacts are stored only online...

Comment: That's the whole idea of Google Sync, the contacts were stored on the old account *online* Sorry mate, looks like you lost them!

Comment: When I restore them, is there a way to save them locally on the phone?

Comment: I suggest you re-edit your question to state that you have a backup of the contacts, and want to know how to restore :) It will make life easier for you :)

Comment: As for restoring, where was the original backup? Titanium Backup?

Comment: I don't have the backup anymore...

Comment: Okie, then why did you state *When I restore them...*? If you don't have the backup, you're pretty much out of luck. Unless someone can come up with a better alternative. Might be best to let this question lurk for a bit until someone has a better answer or idea to help you out... sorry :(

Comment: With "restore" I rather meant adding them manually back :(. I found an older csv contacts file and linked it to my new google account, that made thing easier.